# Showing that if the curvature $\kappa(s) = 0$ for all $s$, then the curve is a straight line

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

**Problem:** Show that if $\kappa(s) = 0$ for all $s$, then the curve $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}(s)$ is a straight line. (Here, $\kappa$ represents curvature.)

**Attempt at solution:** If $\kappa(s) = 0$ for all $s$, then \begin{align*} \frac{d\hat{T}}{ds} = \kappa \hat{N} = 0, \end{align*} where $\hat{N}$ is the unit principal normal. This means, however, that $\hat{T}(s)$ is constant.

So can I now just conclude that $\mathbf{r}$ is a straight line?

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287489/showing-zero-curvature-implies-a-line?rq=1

Comment: Also, though no answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780702/curvature-0-implies-straight-line?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have argued with the normal vector ${\bf n}$, but this vector is only defined in points where $\kappa\ne0$. This brings us into a vicious circle. Argue as follows instead:

If the curve $\gamma:\>s\mapsto{\bf r}(s)$ is parametrized with respect to arc length then by definition $\kappa(s):=|\ddot{\bf r}(s)|$. The assumption $\kappa(s)\equiv0$ then implies $\ddot{\bf r}(s)\equiv{\bf 0}$, and this leads to ${\bf r}(s)={\bf a}+s {\bf u}$, where ${\bf u}$ is a unit vector.

Comment: what is vector a here?

Comment: what if its a plane curve?